# background position IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, background-position

In my CSS I am placing a background like so,

```
background:url(/media/images/body-background.png) bottom left repeat-x;
```

The is a gradient that runs from white to grey, and I am wanting it start at the bottom of my `<body>` and repeat across the screen, however in IE it seems to sit no where near the bottom of my body, is there any reason for this?

URL - http://apigroup.factoryagency.co.uk

Comment: FF10 has problems too...

Comment: Really? I am on FF10 though I am on a mac.

Comment: The background starts at the bottom of the window (view), but if you scroll down it moves up with the page. FF 10.0.2 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Sico87
Just because you are dealing with IE I would avoid doing short hand css, I haven't used it too much but in the past this was an issue with IE. Also, while looking at your site I notice you are giving the body a height of 100%, this might be unnecessary, remove the body height Then try this:

```
body {
    background-image: url("/media/images/body-background.png");
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Tahoma,sans-serif;
}
```

I hope this helps.
By the way, nice job with the site design ;)

Comment: Thanks, still no joy though. Seems to be effecting all browsers on MS systems

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the order of the values like this:

```
background:url(/media/images/body-background.png) repeat-x left bottom;
```